# Do I need a permission to create an avatar or a game character based on an Manga/Anime/Cartoon character?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I was thinking of creating digital characters that then I can use as an avatar in a VR (Virtual Reality) chat or in a small game. It is not initiated by any company or anything so I don't know what are the legal limitation. I just like to show up as the character I like and I know a lot of other people do as well, so I though I could create it, but I am afraid of being sued.

I also like to know if it makes any difference if the product is free or for commercial use. Any other details would also be appreciated of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference if the product is free or commercial use, if it's initiated by a company or an individual. What you are considering would be a "derivative work" and without explicit permission from the copyright holder, it is considered a violation.

Comment: From wiki, it reads if the new work is substantial creative, it receives its own copyright.